# SVG has white space on top when resizing the browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, svg

When I resize the browser a thin white line appears at the top of the SVG. If I resize the page again, it disappears. At certain page widths it reappears and disappears. When I open the SVG file by itself, I don't see any artifacts like that. When I set the SVG background to something crazy like `background: red` I can see that the white line is inside the SVG because it turns red, and not some kind of border or artifact created by a neighboring div. Any ideas on why this might be? So far I've only been able to reproduce it in Chrome and Microsoft Edge. It looks fine in FF and Safari.

This is the page the SVG is on: https://striveworks.us/careers

here's an example:

[image: here's an example of the artifact]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with this, if you disable the background via inspect-elements, the line will disappear, but then the bottom part will be mis-colored.

```css
svg.careers__AnimatedCurveSVG-sc-1587ytp-2 hwGnAC.hwGnAC {
    background: rgb(244, 242, 246);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the SVG's additional white line disappears when we scale the vector image. I suggest changing the height of the **.hwGnAC** element to >= 9rem as lower values do not fix the stated issue.

Comment: thanks for looking at this... are you saying the white space is created because the original SVG is much larger? trying to figure out how to fix this in the SVG itself

Comment: yes............